# Require some guidance on SQL code; subquery row error

Tags: sql, joomla, phpmyadmin

********* **WORKING QUERY BELOW** *********

```
SELECT  a.SubmissionId, a.FieldName, a.FieldValue
 FROM    jos_rsform_submission_values a
         INNER JOIN
         (SELECT SubmissionId, FieldName
         FROM jos_rsform_submission_values b
               WHERE FieldName IN ('Status1', 'Status2', 'Status3', 'Status4', 'Status5', 'Status6', 'Status7', 'Status8', 'Status9', 'Status10')
                AND FieldValue = 'Pending'
                 AND FormId = 28
          ) AS test

         ON a.SubmissionId = test.SubmissionId
WHERE  a.FieldName = 'bayanno1' AND a.FormId = 28
```

*************END*************

I have written the following SQL query:

```
SELECT SubmissionId,
   (SELECT FieldValue
      FROM jos_rsform_submission_values
     WHERE FieldName IN (SELECT FieldName
                           FROM jos_rsform_submission_values
                          WHERE FieldName = 'bayanno1')) AS FieldValue
  FROM jos_rsform_submission_values
 WHERE FieldName IN (SELECT FieldName
                       FROM jos_rsform_submission_values
                      WHERE FieldName = 'Status1')
   AND FieldValue = 'Pending'
   AND FormId = 28
```

I was just wondering if someone could possibly help me in finding the issue of why it's giving me the following error:

> **#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row**

I have two fields in the same column. One is "`bayanno1`" and the other is "`Status1`".

Each of these have a value when a form is submitted on the website. All submissions are linked with a "SubmissionId". This means that if I have 500 submissions of the form, it won't replace the "Status1" value from "SubmissionID" 150 with the "bayanno1" value from "SubmissionId" 120.

For example:

```
(FieldName) "bayanno1"  = "12345" (FieldValue) ; 300 (SubmissionId) ;

(FieldName) "Status1" = "Pending" (FieldValue) ; 300 (SubmissionId) ;
```

I need to replace the VALUE of "Status1" with the VALUE of "bayanno1"; **but only for query purposes. I don't want to replace the actual value, only as a visual query**.

SO the table with the correct SQL should look like this (I will write a PHP query on my webpage to extract the info from the database and insert into a table, however this table is just a very basic example):

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>bayanno1</th>
<th>Status1</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12345</td>
<td>12345</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN instead. And in SQL it's _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: Thanks I will try to do the LEFT JOIN. My mistake on the "fields" wording!

Comment: how would I go about adding a LEFT JOIN to this query? I read up about it and saw what it does, but I can't quite figure out how to insert it into this specific query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edited -- after you have changed the logical requirements of your question...

In simplest terms, you want to extract the `FieldValue` column value from the rows that contain `28` as the `FormId` and `banyanno1` as the `FieldName`.  Furthermore, you want to filter those results to only show `SubmissionIds` which have `Pending` as the value in any of your columns that start with `Status` (assuming you only have those 10 possibilities).

```
SELECT a.SubmissionId, a.FieldValue
FROM jos_rsform_submission_values a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT SubmissionId
     FROM jos_rsform_submission_values
     WHERE FieldName LIKE 'Status%'
       AND FieldValue = 'Pending'
       AND FormId = 28
    ) b
ON a.SubmissionId = b.SubmissionId
WHERE a.FormId = 28
  AND a.FieldName = 'bayanno1'
```

If you want to see all of the columns generated by the join, you can use `a.*, b.*` in your SELECT clause.

As I have told you **repeated times before**, when you are seeking MySQL support here or on JoomlaStackExchange, please accompany your question with a sufficient amount of table structure and data so that volunteers who do not have a local copy of the `rs_forms_submission_values` table can have an easier time of offering assistance.  More importantly, volunteers will have no idea that you have 10 different `Status` rows in your data, so they are doomed to not only fail, but waste their time trying to help you.

If you don't believe me, [listen to Strawberry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333953/2943403).

Finally, I think you would have received faster support at JoomlaStackExchange because many of the volunteers there are likely to have their own local copy of the table and could write and test solutions directly on their own systems.  This is a Joomla related question, so it would certainly be welcome at JSE.

Comment: HI mick, thanks for the reply! Appreciate it! I have however solved it I just haven't updated the answer. I will do so now.

Comment: 1. There is no need to add `a.FieldName` into your SELECT clause because your query logic requires the value to be static. 2. There is no need to use alias `b` if you are only going to reference `test`.  3. There is no need to add `FieldName` into your subquery's SELECT clause because you don't use it. 4. You have fundamentally changed the logical requirement of your question after receiving an answer -- this is rude because it wastes the time of volunteers.

Comment: 5. You still haven't posted any usable data with your question, so your question is Unclear. 6. You posted a solution based on my answer, didn't upvote my solution for being helpful, and you didn't post your solution as an answer.  You still have a bit to learn about how to use the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Your question title asks for guidance.  I have delivered.

Comment: You certainly have and I thank you for your time and effort into your reply. I appreciate it. No I had an error which says "subquery returns more than one row". There was obviously something wrong with my subquery. So I had to do an INNER JOIN which fixed the "subquery returns more than one row" problem via an SQL query. The database is set up in a bad way due to the component, no by me. To explain it I would have to TeamViewer with someone and show them. Even my mate who helped didn't understand the issue until I shared my screen with him because ALL the values are in ONE column in the table.

Comment: I don't understand how I changed the logical requirement. I needed to replace the value of "Status1" with the value of "bayanno1" WHERE the SubmissionId for both FieldValues are the same and FormId = 28. That is the simplest logical terms I can put it. My query was almost there, I just needed to use a INNER JOIN to get the desired result. I'm sorry if you feel this way and I do appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: My first posted answer was perfect for matching `Status1` rows.  When you stated that you needed to check `1` through `10`, my answer became incorrect, by no fault of my own.

Comment: I apologise for that, and yes your answer was correct. I've just been struggling a while with this and when I saw your answer it did put me on the right path for solving it, as you laid it out better logically for me. I've marked your answer as correct.

Comment: I meant no offence and I truly appreciate the time and effort.